# Why aren't Kylo Ren's eyes yellow?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

As far as I always understood it Vader's yellow eyes were because of his fall to the dark side and had nothing to do with the sith themselves.

If that is so as I think then why does Kylo Ren who is also fallen to the dark side not have yellow eyes?

Comment: Perhaps it's a sign that he's still redeemable. When Vader fell, it took an act of unconditional love and ultimate sacrifice by his son to bring him back to the Light. Kylo, on the other hand, is constantly torn between the Light and the Dark, so he could tip either way pretty easily.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - killing people with lightsaber might be redeemable. Being a whiney unstable 30-year-teen.... not so :)

Comment: Kylo Ren forgot to put in his *evil* contact lenses.

Comment: Neither of my parents had yellow eyes and I ended up with brown eyes.

Comment: Whoa... Never heard of yellow eyes...

Answer (score 23):

Not all who fall to the dark side that we see on screen have the yellow effect. E.g. Count Dooku.

[image]

Other dark side users without yellow eyes, include [Asajj Ventress](http://www.starwars.com/databank/asajj-ventress):

[image]

There is a notable difference between Kylo Ren and Vader, one was Sith and the other isn't.

From [JJ Abrams](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/jj-abrams-spills-details-kylo-ren/):

> Kylo Ren is not a Sith

Comment: Hmmm the question is sthough with dooku if he didnt just hide his eyes. as Palpatines at first also were normal eyes....and only in the end were yellow. So the sith seem to have a method of "hiding" them

Comment: Is there a reason Asajj and Dooku have the same strange curved handle design of lightsaber?

Comment: @DVK  If it's okay to reference starwars.wikia.com (as I do not have any other references at hand), Ventress's lightsabers, which once belonged to Dooku's former apprentice Komari Vosa, were given to her by Dooku, whose curved-hilt design ergonomically allowed for "superior finesse and precise blade control".

Comment: @MichaelBecker - it's **definitely OK to reference Wikia in comments** - I'm merely being mildly curious :) . Thanks for the info, that makes sense now!

Comment: @MichaelBecker - However, if you post something as an answer, I would strongly urge you to merely use the Wikia as a guide to help you find the correct canon information, and reference the canon instead of Wikia. Or, at the very least, in the asnwer, quote what Wikia references, so users can check raw canon themselves (`Wikia says XYZ, citing ABC`). Wikia isn't nearly always right, for reasons that far exceed the size of this comment :) There is no explicit **rule** against referencing Wikia, but it can result in much poorer answer

Comment: @DVK , of course, I would never use it as a *primary* reference for an answer (just as I would never use Wikipedia as a primary reference, either... it's an aggregation of references, not a reference itself!) I was merely asking if you personally would accept it as a source for an "unofficial" answer :) Glad to be of help!

Comment: @MichaelBecker - glad to see a kindred spirit approach to this :) Good luck posting, do dip your toes in!

Answer (score 5):

Yellow/red eyes signifies a very, **very** deep corruption by the Dark Side of the Force. It can be masked, as shown by Palpatine, but I doubt that is the case with Kylo Ren.

**Nightsisters** are all Dark Side users, but use it in such a way that it does not corrupt them. Not even Mother Talzin who had her normal eye color. Tradeoff is that they can never be as powerful as a true Sith.

**Count Dooku/Darth Tyrannus** never fully delved into the Dark Side, only tapped into it on occasion. That is why he retained his own eye color. Reason for this is because he never truly wanted to become a true Sith. His "fall" to the Dark Side was due to political reasons.

**Asajj Ventress** may have been a borderline Sith apprentice to Dooku, but she already knew the teachings of the Nightsisters, had some training by the Jedi in terms of Light and Dark, and Dooku himself never strayed too far into the Darkness.

**Savage Opress** was imbued by the Nightsisters' magic. He may or may not have been corrupted. Hard to tell, as his natural eye color already was yellow/orange.

**Snoke** also does not have yellow eyes. He could be masking it, or he's using the Dark Side in another way unseen before, similar to the Nightsisters but possibly more powerful. It's also been said he was looking for the perfect balance between Light and Darkness.

That leads us to **Kylo Ren**. Snoke said Kylo's training was not complete, and he's also expressed his opinions about Kylo Ren being a perfect apprentice due to him being a mix of Light and Dark. So Kylo's training may be more of a Grey focus. But at this point, it's too early to say. Though one thing is for certain: Kylo Ren/Ben Solo does not have yellow eyes because he's not "corrupted" by the Dark Side.

Comment: This isn't a bad answer, though it does go off on a tangent.

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer with some citations to provide a fundament for your arguments; for instance that Dooku's fall to the dark side was political and not that deep - somehow I doubt Palpatine accepting an under-performer after seeing both Anakin and Maul.