# Are the color-changing eyes a sign that happens temporarily when someone first accepts the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith* we can see that Anakin's eyes color turns yellow when he was on Mustafar. Dooku's eyes were always brown and Asajj Ventress often has blue eyes in *The Clone Wars* media, although she uses the Dark Side. Dooku not giving himself over to the Sith as much as Anakin, because he did kill/order others to kill several Jedi and other people in *Episode II* and *The Clone Wars*.

[image: Close up of Anakin inside his hooded robes with his yellow left eye peaking out]

Are the color-changing eyes a sign that happens temporarily when someone first accepts the Dark Side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, Dark Side user's eyes can shift color** temporarily - or even permanently? Palpatine is always seen with yellow eyes after the confrontation with Windu, if I recall correctly.

Anyway, according to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Eye):

> A dark side user's eyes would sometimes change color and burn yellow with a fiery red rim when rage and anger seethed inside them.

---

Why that happens is unknown and explored in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186345/what-makes-sith-lords-eyes-change-color?rq=1).